# How do you map enums to and from the database using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, enumeration

Edit: Ryan raised a good point.  I specifically want to be able to map to and from while still storing human-readable values in the database.  That is, I don't want a bunch of enumeration integers in my database.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-property) you can either leave the type attribute of the property in your mapping file blank or you define it and specify the class name of the enumeration.

Another way would be to convert the enumeration to an int and use the int as the mapped type.

Comment: specifying the class name of the enumeration worked fine for me

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement a custom IUserType. See [this post](http://davidgardiner.blogspot.com/2007/11/using-enum-types-with-nhibernate.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've never used NHibernate, but can't you just set the SQL datatype to int?

Comment: Good point. I should have been more clear with my question. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the type to string:

```
<property name="EnumProperty" Type="string" Length="50" NotNull="true" />
```